# sigv4-post-example using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am trying to generate the same signature from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html using python,

```
DateKey = hmac.new(b'AWS4wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY', b'20151229', hashlib.sha256).digest()

DateRegionKey = hmac.new(DateKey, b'us-east-1', hashlib.sha256).digest()

DateRegionServiceKey = hmac.new(DateRegionKey, b's3', hashlib.sha256).digest()

SigningKey = hmac.new(DateRegionServiceKey, b'aws4_request', hashlib.sha256).digest()

signature = hmac.new(other_policy, SigningKey, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
```

But my signature is `cb0b0ec487fd5e01382c9c3b6b6a6dfa170da312ddab58a4b18869e7413951be` and expected signature is `46503978d3596de22955b4b18d6dfb1d54e8c5958727d5bdcd02cc1119c60fc9`

Where am I doing wrong ?

Note

```
other_policy = b'''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'''
```

from the http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html

Comment: What if your `other_policy` content itself is incorrect? After correcting the issue with `hmac.new(other_policy, SigningKey, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()`, i checked signing the same key using the Java sample source code and the digest is same from both Java and Python code. So most probably you are using the wrong content for `other_policy` value

Comment: I think either AWS doc outdated or `other_policy` not correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Bug in the code**

Your code to generate the signing key looks fine.  However, when you generate the signature, the parameters are switched around.  The pseudocode is:

```
Hex(HMAC-SHA256(SigningKey, StringToSign))
```

So instead of

```
signature = hmac.new(other_policy, SigningKey, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
```

you should have

```
signature = hmac.new(SigningKey, other_policy, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
```

**Still wrong?**

This produces the following signature, which despite the Amazon documentation, I believe is correct for the provided base64 string to sign:

```
8afdbf4008c03f22c2cd3cdb72e4afbb1f6a588f3255ac628749a66d7f09699e
```

So why does Amazon say the signature should be `465039...c60fc9`???

I'm sorry to say I have no idea.  I suspect the documentation may actually be inaccurate, either with respect to the signature value or with respect to the input parameter values used to generate it (secret key, date, region, service, string to sign).

I do feel like I'm going out on a limb a bit suggesting such a thing, but at the same time, I know from experience that not every piece of technical documentation online is 100% accurate (even when produced by a reputable source).

I couldn't reproduce this signature no matter what I tried.  I'd **love** to see an answer that successfully produces this hash.

**Evidence**

There are really only two things going on here:

- Calculate a signing key.
- Pass it along with the "string to sign" to a hashing function, to generate the signature.

Your code produces the expected signing key using the parameters in the example under ["Deriving the Signing Key with Other Languages" here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html#signature-v4-examples-python).  This suggests you're calculating the signing key correctly. Python code [here](https://gist.github.com/mikepatrick/42c6276fead2c02175a6bc1587ed29dd).

Your code also produces the expected signature when using the parameters from [this example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr//sigv4-calculate-signature.html).  This suggests you're both calculating the correct signing key and the correct signature.  Python code [here](https://gist.github.com/mikepatrick/fca1e977501827a76ef7d5bf5242bf05).

Running the parameters from your question through some existing Python code that I know to work with several services (based on [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html)) also produces the same `8afdb...9699e` signature.

I also threw the [java signing code into an existing spring boot application](https://gist.github.com/mikepatrick/cce0ac20db3db0d0527b2ef6ffbf2daa), and it also produces the same `8afdb...9699e` signature for your input parameters.

**What to try?**

I suggest you assume your signing code is good, and the AWS documentation on this particular page is mistaken.  After all, your code works fine with at least two other AWS examples.

Sign a **real** request, using *your* credentials, *your* bucket policy, *your* region, the current date, etc.

Then post the sample form and see if it works.  If it doesn't work, you could update the question with the error you get from the form `POST`.

**Update** (7/15/2018)

AWS has updated their documentation, and [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html) now contains the correct signature.  The incorrect version [can be viewed here](https://web.archive.org/web/20171219020807/http://docs.aws.amazon.com:80/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html), for historical purposes.

Interestingly, the wayback machine suggests that the page was correct until at least June 23, 2017.  By July 14 it had changed to the wrong signature, and it stayed incorrect *at least* until December 19, 2017 (over 5 months!).

Comment: +1 for detailed information, I am trying to upload images from client(javascript) to s3, And generating s4 signature from backend(python). Unfortunately I am not able upload image. Because of signature missmatch. Do you have any doc for complete S4 process for my need. I tried multiple ways but I failed.

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation specific to S3 that's any better than what you already linked to.  However, that example _does_ work for me if I update the dates and point it at a bucket I own.  Here are the [files I used to test](https://github.com/mikepatrick/s3-upload-sig4).