# Python AWS S3 POST Signing

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, django-rest-framework

In Python Django, I am implementing server side AWS S3 POST file upload policy and signature creation, which is sent to client. Via RESTful API, iOS client takes the values and POSTs the file directly to AWS S3. I am not using PUT because this will eventually be multi-part and be used in iOS background.

This post, is similar to [sigv4-post-example using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47701044/sigv4-post-example-using-python). Like those responding suggested, I assumed that the AWS Documentation was flawed. So went ahead and tried with "real" values, without success.

Using the example that AWS posts at:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html

I have successfully implemented the policy generation/base64 encoding. However, I am struggling with getting the signature to match the value AWS publishes in that example. I implement the - def sign - & - def getSignatureKey - as AWS shows at:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html#signature-v4-examples-python

Here are the code snippets in question, using values in the AWS example:

```
     #policy_string is string version of json generated policy, working great!!
     policy_bytes = policy_string.encode("utf-8")
     encoded_policy = base64.b64encode(policy_bytes)

     #using values provided in AWS's test case
     sign_key = getSignatureKey('wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY', '20151229', 'us-east-1', 's3')
     signature = hmac.new(sign_key, policy_bytes, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
     print("signature = ", signature)
```

This produces the signature:
00e98ae3199cdbfeba701f9efa66510f23f0295ab6d6f4d14202f8ef2d11956c

But the version AWS publishes is:
8afdbf4008c03f22c2cd3cdb72e4afbb1f6a588f3255ac628749a66d7f09699e

I have tried several permutations of the key/message in the signing process without progress. Has anyone successfully gotten this to work properly?

If anyone is still struggling with getting the policy encoded, I found that you need to end each line in the policy with '\r\n' (CRLF). I did it by appending each line in the policy to a string, one by one. No combination of json.dumps or pprint succeeded in getting me to the right string construction.

Comment: So I identified one of my issues. In the line of code where the signature is generated, the msg value should be encoded_policy, not policy_bytes. But after fixing that the signature does not match the AWS published value.

Answer (score 0):

The code, as fixed using encoded policy as msg field value, now works. That is fixing the line of code:

from -

```
signature = hmac.new(sign_key, policy_bytes, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
```

to -

```
signature = hmac.new(sign_key, encoded_policy, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
```

fixed the problem.

Comment: Hi, I know it is an old post. Can you share the code for converting the json post policy to string? I have issues with \r\n... Thanks in advance.